# Как отсортировать вывод с запроса

Tags: laravel

Есть запрос, который выводит все ид дополнительных полей по их названию

```
Field::whereIn('title', $field)->pluck('id');
```

`$field` - Массив с название доп. полей

Например:

`Field - БД`

```
id | title
1  | Категория 1
2  | Категория 2
```

В массиве `$field` хранится название доп.поле в виде `['Категория 2','Категория 1']`

При запросе - `Field::whereIn('title', $field)->pluck('id');` в результате мы получим поряд ид - 1,2.
То есть отсортированный по ид, а возможно сделать вывод именно в том порядке, который есть в массиве `$field`?

UPD

'Решил' проблему таким - 'методом '

```
$fie = Field::get();
$asd = [];
foreach ($field as $f) {//Перебираем массив с названиями, по порядку
  foreach ($fie as $i) {//Перебираем все имеющиеся доп. поля
    if($f == $i->title) {//Проверяем на совпадения в названии
      $asd[] = $i->id;//Добавляем ид в массив
    }
  }
}
```

На выходе получаю массив с ид в нужном мне порядке, возможно есть более щедящий способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать функцию MySql FIELD():

```
Field::whereIn('title', $field)
    ->orderByRaw("FIELD(title, '" . implode("','", $field) . "')")
    ->pluck('id');
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_field.asp